# Renaming Multiple files replacing part of the filename only in ASCII/Unicode

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with many files and I want to rename all of them replacing only part of the file name...

Ex:
Rename this

```
¸Ó¸®30_³²_244.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_245.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_246.pal
¸Ó¸®30_³²_247.pal
```

to this

```
¸Ó¸®45_³²_244.pal
¸Ó¸®45_³²_245.pal
¸Ó¸®45_³²_246.pal
¸Ó¸®45_³²_247.pal
```

Here is my code:

```
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
Set "Pattern=30" 
Set "Replace=31" 
For /f %%# in ('dir /b "*.pal"') Do (
  Set "File=%%~nx#"
  Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!" 
) 
Pause&Exit
```

Comment: So you're just changing the `30` to a `45`?

Comment: yes... I tried a batch file i searched but it said "The system cannot find the file specified." this is the batch file code I used
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=30"
Set "Replace=31"

For /f %%# in ('dir /b "*.pal"') Do (
    Set "File=%%~nx#"
    Ren "%%#" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Pause&Exit

Comment: your code works for me. What problem do you have?

Comment: I don't believe you can use `%%#` as the loop index on a `FOR`; change that to a letter (e.g., `FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR /B "*.PAL")...`) instead.

Comment: I tried changing %%# to %%I but still doesn't work.. I guess it has something to do with the filename... it is in unicode..

Comment: If you are running on Windows 7 or later, try rewriting the process in PowerShell.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know PowerShell... can you help me with this?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin_ `%%#` works fine (although I also prefer "normal" letters)

Comment: You're using a `for /f` loop, which reads bytes from a child process using a pipe and decodes it line by line according to the current console codepage. If you temporarily switch to codepage 65001 (UTF-8) via `chcp.com 65001`, it should properly encode and decode on both ends of the pipe. But there's no reason to use a `for /f` loop here. You could do this with `for %%a in (*.pal)`, which uses native Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and testing... I finally got it to work with PowerShell using this code...

```
get-childItem '*.pal' | rename-item -newname { $_.name -replace '40_','55_' }
```

Now I want to know how to change these

```
file_0000.txt
file_0001.txt
file_0002.txt
file_0003.txt
file_0010.txt
file_0100.txt
```

to these

```
file_0.txt
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_10.txt
file_100.txt
```

Comment: replace `_0` with `_`?